# Can decidability be thought of as having the possibility to write the negation of your formula without a negation?

Tags: logic

A proposition $x$ is decidable when $\vdash_{LJ} x\lor\neg x$.

I have the intuition that this happens iff $\neg x$ "has computational content", or in other words, can be expressed "directly", without a negation.

Is my intuition at least on the right track? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you exactly mean with "decidable" ? A single statement is always decidable (with the usual definition of "decidable" , even if we do not know whether it is true) because there is an algorithm giving the correct result. Maybe you mean with "decidable" that the statement is either provable or disprovable. In this case, one possible way is to show that the negation must be false. The excluded middle then guarantees that it must be true.

Comment: @Peter: excluded middle does not hold in the intuitionistic system $LJ$ that the OP is working in. It is also not the case, even in classical logic, that there is an algorithm giving the truth value of any statement.

Comment: If  the intuitionistic system $LJ$ proves $x \lor \lnot x$, then we know that either $\vdash_{LJ}  x$ or $\vdash_{LJ} \lnot x$ (this is called the disjunction property). If $P$ is a predicate letter and $x$ is $\lnot(P \lor \lnot P)$, then LJ proves $\lnot x$ and hence also $x \lor \lnot x$, but I can't see how you can express $\lnot x$ without using negation (or a substitute for it like $\lnot x\equiv x \to \bot$). However, I don't think this means $\lnot x$ has no computational content: the computational content of $\lnot x$ is that given $x$ you can derive a contradiction.